# When do we need compactness to tell if a subset of a metric space is a metric space of its own?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Theorem 2.33 in Rudin's book, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, is:

> **2.33 Theorem**  Suppose $K\subset Y\subset  X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

Right after it, he comments:

> By virtue of this theorem we are able, in many situations, to regard compact sets as metric spaces in their own right, without paying any attention to any embedding space

I don't understand this comment.
That is, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X$ be a subset. $(Y,d)$ is a metric space in light of Rudin's explanation from p. 31, which is:

> It is important to observe that every subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ is a metric space in its own right, with the same distance function.

Hence, $(Y,d)$ is a metric space and we know that without theorem 2.33.

So why 'By virtue...'?

Comment: I agree that this is not very well formulated, but the "in their own right" is refering to the compacity of $K$, and not to the fact that it is metric.

Comment: What Rudin is trying to say is that compactness is independent on the choice of embedding space. Which btw does not follow from theorem 2.33. It's a weird statement.